# Removing spaces before querying database in Active Record works in Rails C but not controller

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am setting up an AJAX response to auto-populate the data list on a search bar as the user types. So far it works perfectly, except that if the user adds additional spaces in the word, it won't find the result. I am trying to remove the spaces when querying the database for similar results by adding some additional SQL into my .where arguments. It still works for the previous case of when there are no extra spaces, but when the user enters extra spaces it does not work.

The `Listing.where("replace(city,' ','')  like replace(?, ' ', '')", query)` query works perfectly when I simply run it in Rails console for testing, so I don't understand why it's not working from the controller method.

Here is my controller method:

```
    def search
        query = "%#{params[:query]}%"

        # Paginate full list of matching listings for rendering search results to html
        @listings = Listing.where("city like ?", query).page

        # Find unique list of matching cities for ajax requests to autocomplete search bar
        @cities = Listing.where("replace(city,' ','')  like replace(?, ' ', '')", query).pluck(:city).uniq
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { @listings.page }
            format.js { render :json => @cities }
        end
    end
```

EDIT: Server response when method is executed:

```
Started GET "/listings/search?query=Kuala%20Selangor%20" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-07-29 01:55:31 +0800
Processing by ListingsController#search as JSON
  Parameters: {"query"=>"Kuala Selangor "}
   (1.5ms)  SELECT "listings"."city" FROM "listings" WHERE (replace(city,' ','')  like replace('%Kuala Selangor %', ' ', ''))
  ↳ app/controllers/listings_controller.rb:46
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
```

Comment: can you show the actual SQL fired?

Comment: @emaillenin I added to my original post

Answer (score 0):

Look for a TRIM method to strip whitespace around the city name.

Also, it looks like you're replacing spaces in city name in the DB query, and not in the user input. I would make sure to format the user input to be trimmed, and a single whitespace between words.

If the city name is "St. Paul" and you do a DB search for "St.Paul" and the user types in " St.   Paul " it is never going to match.

Comment: In fact, this turned out to be a stranger issue. I've changed my query to strip the query for leading/trailing white spaces in the search (`Listing.where("city like ?", "%#{params[:query].strip}%")`) which actually is returning the correct results to my JS file, but for some reason once it includes trailing white spaces it stops appending the options to the list, even though it has the necessary data.

Comment: Ok, so the %___% match string will match against the database matching (anything)CITY_NAME(anything). If I understand correctly the problem is with whitespace in the *results*. You can trim the results when they get back, or you can query SELECT trim(both ' ' from city) AS city FROM xxx which will trim the result set on the DB side. However, I would look to your client side code for why trailing whitespace is causing results to not show up. *edit: changed trim from MySQL to PostgreSQL